# preg_match everything between first SELECT and last FROM

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to have a regular expression that matches everything between the first SELECT and the last FROM in a SQL statement with PHP.
To put this into an example:

```
SELECT
    `t1`.`id`,
    `t1`.`created`,
    (
        SELECT
            `t2`.`content`
        FROM
            `table2` `t2`
        WHERE
            `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`id`
    ) `sub`
FROM
    `table1` `t1`
```

In the statement above statement I want to match:

```
`t1`.`id`,
    `t1`.`created`,
    (
        SELECT
            `t2`.`content`
        FROM
            `table2` `t2`
        WHERE
            `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`id`
    ) `sub`
```

I tried doing this myself, but I can't get it working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=SELECT\s)(.*)(?=\sFROM)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/15

Comment: Thanks, almost working as I want it. I just ran into another problem with this query: http://regex101.com/r/lD8uH4/1. It goes wrong when I put another select from statement in the where clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a basic regular expression to achieve this ...

```
preg_match('~SELECT(.*)FROM~si', $text, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

[<kbd>**Code Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/208255)

Answer (score 1):

Use DOTALL modifier to make dot to match even newline characters also. `\K` in the below regex would discard the previously matched characters from printing.

```
(?s)SELECT[^\n]*\n\K.*(?=[^\n]*FROM)
```

OR

```
(?s)SELECT[^\n]*\n\K.*(?=\n[^\n]*?FROM)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bD5iV3/3)